# Write date, time, and time zone

Tags: datetime

### Background

Looking to include the current date, time, and timezone within a PDF.

### Problem

The `datetime` package does not provide a macro for the current timezone.

### Question

How would you write a macro in LaTeX to create a date such as:

```
Sun Jan 09 20:17:18 EST 2011
```

### Working

Thus far:

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\shortdayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year}
\shortmonthname{} \twodigit{\day} \hhmmsstime{}
EST \number\year
```

The timezone (EST) eludes me.

### Related

- http://blog.jansoehlke.com/?Recipes&nr=16
- http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/datetime.pdf

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the offset from GMT using the pdfTeX primitive `\pdfcreationdate`: (no doubt LuaTeX has something similar)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\grabtimezone #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\grabtimezoneB}
\def\grabtimezoneB #1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\grabtimezoneC}
\def\grabtimezoneC #1#2'#3'{sign: #1 / hr: #2 / min: #3}
\expandafter \grabtimezone\pdfcreationdate
\end{document}
```

If you need to convert this into a timezone string, you'll need to define a dictionary of timezones to match up with the time offsets. Since I think this is a many-to-one mapping for many time zones, I'm not sure how that would work.

Once you work out exactly what you need for your application, I suggest writing to the `datetime` author to add such a feature to that package.

**Update**. To get a crude lookup table for getting string output for the timezone, you can try something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{timezone+0930}{CST}
\@namedef{timezone+1000}{EST}
\@namedef{timezone+1030}{CST'}% daylight savings
\def\grabtimezone #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\grabtimezoneB}
\def\grabtimezoneB #1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\grabtimezoneC}
\def\grabtimezoneC #1#2'#3'{%
  \@ifundefined{timezone#1#2#3}
    {No timezone for `#1#2#3'}
    {\@nameuse{timezone#1#2#3}}%
}
\def\timezone{\expandafter\grabtimezone\pdfcreationdate}
\makeatother

\timezone
```

Comment: will not work if you are minus UTC time i.e., plus sign needs to be -!

Comment: @Yiannis good point. thanks; I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is now the [`filemod`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filemod) package which can return the file modification date of any file (which can be found by TeX). It is based on the `\pdffilemoddate` macro. It works with pdf(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX, but not with Xe(La)TeX.

If you want the time when the main file was last changed use `\jobname` as filename in the macros below. If you really want the compile time you can
use the macros with a trick:

```
\edef\pdfilemoddate#1{\pdfcreationdate}
```

and then keep the `{<filename>}` argument empty.

---

You can print, i.e. typeset the date, time and timezone using

```
\filemodprint{<filename>}
```

Only the date or time+timezone are printed with

```
\filemodprintdate{<filename>}
\filemodprinttime{<filename>}
```

They use the `\thefilemoddate` and `\thefilemodtime` to format the result.
These macro get `{<YYYY>}{<MM>}{<DD>}` or `{<HH>}{<mm>}{<SS>}{<TZ>}` as arguments, respectively. You can redefine these to print the date or time in a custom format. There is also `\thefilemod` for `\filemodprint` which gets all seven arguments and by default calls the other two macros.

You can also create your own macro with seven arguments and use:

```
\filemodparse{\mymacro}{<filename>}
```

Then the timezone would be `#7`.

Comment: With `\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\filemodprintdate{<filename>}
\filemodprinttime{<filename>}
}` I get 0000/00/00 00:00:00 Z  I can't see what's wrong...

Comment: @Joel: which LaTeX are you using? PdfLaTeX, LuaLaTex, XeLaTeX? Does it work with the same macros inside the normal text, i.e. not in the footer?